# Apply() function not working as it should

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to apply a function which would delete the first 4 characters of the row called "gncr" if the cell starts with GNCR instead of the actual number. The function does work, but it seems like it does not return and my dataframe remains unchanged.

I've tried a lot of things but none of them worked

```
def extract_gncr(gncr):
    if gncr[0] == 'G':
        gncr = gncr[4:]
    elif not gncr.isdigit():
        gncr = ''
    print(gncr) #This shows me the fonction actually works
    return(gncr)

def merge_data(primary_df):
    foreign_df = pd.read_exce(r"somefile.xlsx")
    #extract the number from "GNCRxxxx"
    foreign['GNCR'] = foreign_df['GNCR'].apply(extract_gncr)
    primary['GNCR'] = primary_df['GNCR'].apply(extract_gncr)
    #foreign and primary remains unchanged
    [...]
```

Comment: Can you make a [MCVE] ? It is hard to debug your problem without knowing the data that poses the potential problem.

Comment: what is `foreign`? You define `foreign_df`. Seems like a typo to me.

Comment: please *always* use the generic [python] tag for all python-related questions. use version-specific tags at your discretion. Note: Python 3 is generally assumed, seeing as Python 2 is rapidly approaching it's official end of life.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably not the apply function.  It could be an issue with variable scope.  Try printing foreign and primary inside of merge_data.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the unconvenience,
this fonction actually works, the problem was somewhere else, I fixed it. 
Thx for the answers!